# Creating a temporary file from standard input

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, pipe

Say I have a standard input stream of *file contents* and a command that expects a *file name* as an argument and I want to run that command on a file made up of the standard input stream’s file contents.

For instance, instead of the command

```
imageviewer mouse.jpg
```

I want some magical line `magic` that makes this equivalent to

```
cat mouse.jpg | magic
```

What would this `magic` look like in `zsh` or `bash`?

Preferably, I would like it to look like

```
cat mouse.jpg | submagic | xargs imageviewer
```

that is, I would like `submagic` to create a temporary file from the standard input stream and output the created file’s file name.

The lines `magic` or `submagic` should be shell pipelines using only bash or zsh commands, their builtins, GNU coreutils and the likes.

---

This is the entire question. Below is merely clarification and background because people kept misinterpreting what I meant.

---

Okay, so I thought I made it clear, but it seems like I didn’t: I *really* want to have a pipeline doing the equivalent of

```
imageviewer mouse.jpg
```

that *begins exactly* with `cat mouse.jpg | …`. That is, I *really* want *exactly* a line `magic` or `submagic` such that *exactly* the pipelines above work – I meant my question literally.

This means in particular that the following suggested solutions won’t do:

- beginning the pipeline with `tmpfile = $(mktemp); cat mouse.jpg | …`
- rewriting it as `imageviewer =(cat mouse.jpg)`
- rewriting it as `echo mouse.jpg | xargs imageviewer`
- using a function or a binary to solve it, say by defining `function magic () { … }`

It can be said that what I’m interested in is whether it’s possible to write an alias `alias magic='…'` or `alias submagic='…'` such that one of the above pipelines work and such that definition of these aliases contains nothing more than bash or zsh commands, GNU coreutils and the likes – nothing self-written.

*Another comment*. You make take `imageviewer` to be `feh` or `sxiv` or something.

*Background*. This question came to me when I tried opening several image files attached to a mail using my mail client `neomutt`. Neomutt offers to tag attached files and then to pipe the file contents to a command line you may type in. So here, I can only give a command line that performs something on a given standard input stream. That’s where the question came from. But I’m not interested in the original problem, but only in this very question.

Comment: The answers you have provide all the pieces to come up with a function: `function magic (){ tmpfile=$(mktemp); cat - >"$tmpfile"; printf '%s\n' "$tmpfile"; }`. This will work exactly the way you are asking for: `cat mouse.jpg | magic | xargs gwenview` (`gwenview` is the image viewer I have and which I'm testing with). If this falls short of your expectations then I fear you'll have to clarify even more...

Comment: @fra-san Yeah, it’s a function not a pipeline of bash or zsh commands. : ( I’ve added further clarification. I was very precise in what I’ve written, but it obviously hasn’t been clear at all that I really am only interested in that and nothing else.

Comment: With your edits you add more and more restrictions to rule out all proposed solutions but you don't explain the reason for your strange requirements.

Comment: @Bodo I don’t *add* restrictions. I can leave out all the edits and the question would still be the same. The edits are merely clarifications because people kept interpreting my question loosely as “I want to do roughly this.”, whereas I meant “I want to do exactly this”. I’ll add a small background for an explanation for these requirements.

Comment: And what's the reason for the restriction "nothing self-written"? It would be simple to create a shell script that writes the data from stdin to a temporary file, runs `imageviewer` (or a command specified as cmdline arg) and removes the temporary file when `imageviewer` has terminated.

Comment: @Bodo That’s why I didn’t give the background originally: I don’t care about the original problem too much. It’s only in solving this original problem that I was asking myself the very question that I have posted here. It just seemed to me that what I wanted should be possible, I merely didn’t know how.

Comment: @Bodo Is there yet still something you want me to clarify or improve? Can you otherwise remove your downvote?

Comment: @Bodo Seriously – do you have any further suggestions for improving the question or did you just downvote because you thought I was being picky?

Comment: @Bodo The question has been answered. Apparently the question has been comprehensible after all. Just so you know, in case you want to remove a downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To meet the exact requirements of your question, you can do:

```
cat mouse.jpg | { tf=$(mktemp); cat >"$tf"; echo "$tf"; } | xargs imageviewer
```

Comment: I found this solution useful enough that I turned it to a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/claui/submagic) including a README, man page, and [AUR package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/submagic). Of course the command is named `submagic`.

Answer (score 9):

In `bash` at least, with the use of a *process substitution*:

```
utility <( some_other_utility )
```

This would present `utility` with a *file name*.  When `utility` opens the file and reads from it, it will read the standard output of `some_other_utility`.

---

Your example:

```
cat mouse.jpg | submagic | xargs imageviewer
```

I'm assuming that this is meant to send the *file name* `mouse.jpg` to `imageviewer`, as it doesn't make sense to send the contents of a JPEG file through `xargs`.

That could be done through just

```
echo 'mouse.jpg' | xargs imageviewer
```

or

```
xargs imageviewer <<<'mouse.jpg'
```

in `bash`.

Sending the contents of `mouse.jpg` to `imageviewer` can be done with

```
cat mouse.jpg | imageviewer /dev/stdin
```

or, using the process substitution, with

```
imageviewer <( cat mouse.jpg )
```

Using a temporary file:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
cat mouse.jpg >"$tmpfile"

imageviewer "$tmpfile"

rm "$tmpfile"
```

Possibly,

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
cat mouse.jpg | { cat >"$tmpfile"; echo "$tmpfile"; } | xargs imageviewer
rm "$tmpfile"
```

This pipeline relies on the fact that `xargs` would wait with executing `imageviewer` until it had read the filename from the middle part of the pipeline.  The filename would not be outputted by the middle command until the temporary file had been created.

Comment: There might be an issue if `imageviewer` wants to seek the file

Comment: Thanks – that doesn’t answer the question, though. That I start with a standard input stream of some process is a restriction. In your answer, the output from `some_other_utility` isn’t handled as a standard input stream. I specifically need some command that I can put in lieu of `magic` or `submagic`. Maybe think of the question as: “Write an alias `alias magic=…` such that the above works”.

Comment: @k.stm Your example does not make much sense to me. Could you clarify please?

Comment: @Torin This is a restriction set out by the question.  If the data is a stream, then it's likely not seekable to start with.

Comment: @Kusalananda I think k.stm is asking about receiving a stream of data, writing it all to a temporary file and then running the command with the temporary filename as a parameter.

Comment: It would be fairly easy to write a small binary that takes the standard input, creates a temporary file with its contents and outputs that temporary file’s file name. Say the name of that binary is `submagic`. I want to compose an elegant equivalent of it with bash or zsh.

Comment: @k.stm Since all parts of a pipeline runs concurrently, you `submagic` command would possibly start _after_ `imageviewer`, which means the file that it created would not be available for `imageviewer`.  This is regardless of whether it's implemented in the shell or in C.  You would have to _first_ create the file, then invoke `imageviewer`.

Comment: @k.stm But see latest edit to the answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda `xargs` provides `-a` option that lets the user specify the input file: `xargs -a mouse.jpg imageviewer`.

Comment: @NikoGambt Not on a non-GNU system. Besides, I very much doubt that you'd like to send the actual JPEG data to _`xargs`_.

Comment: @Kusalananda The thing is I'm not sure whether `imageviewer` is an actual program for processing an image, or if it's just a random example. After all, `imageviewer` is mentioned following the phrase "For instance..."

Comment: @NikoGambt In any case, it is highly uncommon to want to pass raw JPEG data to `xargs`.  If it instead of `mouse.jpg` was a file containing text, then it would make more sense.  `xargs` would take the data, and invoke the utility with the data as command line arguments.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yeah, no one would normally break up an image file into chunks and process them individually, especially with a program called "imageviewer". However, there's a possibility that the author simply made up an example (albeit one that doesn't make sense with `xargs`). If that is indeed a random example, there's not much point in dwelling into whether it makes sense to pass an image file into `xargs`. However, if `imageviewer` is indeed the intended program, then it does not make sense to use `xargs`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Hm, since `mktemp | xargs nvim` works for me, I don’t think that “Because of concurrency, the file whose name is given to `xargs` has to exist before invoking the pipeline.” isn’t entirely true. (Otherwise, what I want would be impossible and then that would be the answer to the question.)

Comment: @k.stm `mktemp | xargs utility` works because `xargs` reads from the pipe and waitl for `mktemp` to write to it.  `mktemp | utility` would not work unless the utility expects to read the filename from standard input.  When I wrote that previous comment, I forgot that you had added `xargs` to the pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

After a clarification of `submagic` in the question I edited the answer.

In `zsh` you can create a temporary file from the output of a command with `=( ... )`. In contrast to `<( ... )` which may use a device file like `/dev/fd...` or a named pipe the form `=( ... )` creates a seekable temporary file. See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Process-Substitution

Assuming that `cat mouse.jpg` is only an example for any command that sends image data to stdout, you can use

```
imageviewer =(cat mouse.jpg)
```

If you need the temporary  file created by zsh to have a particular extension, you can set the [`TMPSUFFIX` special variable](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-TMPSUFFIX)):

```
(TMPSUFFIX=.jpg; imageviewer =(cat mouse.jpg))
```

**second update**

If you insist on the syntax

```
cat mouse.jpg | submagic | xargs imageviewer
```

it would be possible to create a script `submagic` similar to the commands already proposed in Kusalananda's answer.

```
#! /bin/sh

# A fixed name allows multiple runs without creating lots of files and
# allows a simple script to remove the file afterwards.
TMPFILE=/tmp/submagic.tmp.jpg
rm -f "$TMPFILE" && cat > "$TMPFILE" && echo "$TMPFILE"
```

In contrast to shell mechanisms like `=( cat mouse.jpg )` this would not remove `$TMPFILE` after running `imageviewer`.

If you can run a second script after running `imageviewer` this could remove the file if it knows the name.

Script `submagic-cleanup`

```
#! /bin/sh

# A fixed name allows a simple script for cleaning up.
TMPFILE=/tmp/submagic.tmp.jpg
rm -f "$TMPFILE"
```

Then you could  run

```
cat mouse.jpg | submagic | xargs imageviewer
submagic-cleanup
```

Comment: Thanks, that still doesn’t answer my question. I need an alias for `submagic` such that exactly `cat mouse.jpg | submagic | xargs imageviewer` works.

Comment: @k.stm Why do you have this requirement? This looks like hou have a specific (difficult) solution in mind while there might be other solutions for your real problem.